# Executing rxjs observable function recursively

Tags: rxjs

I'm new to RxJs. I'm trying to run observable function recursively with no luck. I want to print in this order.

> form textbox icon textarea

Here is what I tried so far. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
const args = {
  name: 'form',
  children: [{
    name: 'textbox',
    children: [{
      name: 'icon',
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'textarea',
    children: []
  }]
};

import { of, from, Observable, concat } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, concatAll, combineAll } from 'rxjs/operators';

const render = (component) => {
 return new Observable<any>(observer => {
   console.log(component.name);
   concat(...component.children.map(x => render(x)))
   .subscribe(() => observer.next());
 });
};

render(args).subscribe(() => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: Why are you using rxjs to convert a single static structure? I think you are using the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @Davy that's a sample code. In actual code instead of console.log some async stuff will be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the correct order. If I've missed something, please comment:

```js
const { of, concat } = rxjs;

const args = {
  name: 'form',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'textbox',
      children: [
          {
            name: 'icon',
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
    {
      name: 'textarea',
      children: []
    }
  ]
};

const render = (component) => concat(of(component), ...component.children.map(render));

render(args).subscribe(({name}) => console.log(name));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.4/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you.